# response returning null for no reason rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I getting null in return when in fact i have data in the database, I don't where the problem lies, pretty frustrated by this, if I am not calling is_valid then it throws an assertion error but anyways data is still empty

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**View**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):  
    product_data = Product.objects.all()
    print(product_data)
    serialized_data = ProductSerializer(data = product_data, many =True)
    data = {}
    if serialized_data.is_valid():
        data['status']='valid'
    else:
        data['status']='not valid'
        
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: What do you mean that you are getting null in return? Where do you see this null?

Comment: I suggest adding `print(data)` before and after the `if` statement. For more tips on debugging your code check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice queryset is getting printed but serialized is data is empty , i get nothing from it, now because i am testing it via dictionary i am getting only `data['status']='not valid'` in result which suggests `if` is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the DRF serializer in the wrong way, try to use the ***`instance`*** argument, instead of `data` while serializing the data.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):
    product_qs = Product.objects.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(instance=product_qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: yes, it worked can you explain it a bit @JPG